# Angular 2 Toggle Views On Click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a bootstrap card which has three different content views inside it. I am controlling the view of each of the separate data sets onclick of a link for each one. The problem is when I click a link it does not hide the previous one. I am having trouble getting the function right with typescript.

in my component.ts file

```
  public showEquifax:boolean = true;
  public showExperian:boolean = false;
  public showTransunion:boolean = false;
```

Then in my html file

```
 <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Credit Report Navigation">
                    <button (click)="showEquifax = !showEquifax" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Equifax Report </button>
                    <button (click)="showExperian = !showExperian" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Experian Report </button>
                    <button (click)="showTransunion = !showTransunion" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Transunion Report </button>
                </div>
```

Based on this logic how can I change the `boolean` value of the functions to `false` when the link clicked value gets changed to `true`

I tried to do something like this,

```
public showEquifax() {
    showExperian() = false;
    showTransunion() = false;
    return true;
}
```

But I get an error for left-hand side assignment expression.

How can I write each of these boolean functions to change the others to false when the current function is set to true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is: when one is shown, the other two are hidden, right? What about change your logic to something like this:

```
// On the class, instead of 3 booleans
private shown: string = 'EQUIFAX';
```

Then, the buttons would act like this:

```
<button (click)="shown = 'EQUIFAX'" type=="button" ...
<button (click)="shown = 'EXPERIAN'" type="button" ...
<button (click)="shown = 'TRANSUNION'" type="button" ...
```

Then you could show your components like this:

```
<div *ngIf="shown === 'EQUIFAX'">
    content here
</div>

<div *ngIf="shown === 'EXPERIAN'"> ... </div>
<div *ngIf="shown === 'TRANSUNION'"> ... </div>
```

Comment: This is great man. Thanks for making that so simple. Would you mind telling me also how to do something like this on a button like I am using? routerLinkActive="active" which only works for router links I assume. Basically how to show the button as active on page load?

Comment: Just add a CSS class conditionally, like: `<button [class]="shown === 'EQUIFAX' ? 'activeClass' : ''">`, with `activeClass` being a CSS class with the style to the active button, like `.activeClass { background:red; }`.